# Unable to get focus on the action button in snackbar when the snackbar is shown with touch mode enabled

Tags: android, material-design, accessibility, talkback, snackbar

I am trying to get the focus directly to the action button in the snackbar when the snackbar is being shown so that users are made aware that there is some action that can be performed with the alert message as shown in the snackbar. Note: this is for talkback mode. 
I have tried using `requestFocus()` and `sendAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_VIEW_FOCUSED);` but either way the focus seems to stay in the fragment.
Also I am facing a similar issue with material showcase view action button. 
Any tips on how to get the focus there?

Answer (score 1):

```
  snackbar.getView().findViewById(com.google.android.material.R.id.snackbar_action).sendAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_VIEW_FOCUSED);
```

Remember to call this after a certain delay so that accessibility get attach to snackbar widget

Answer (score 0):

Call `snackbar.getView().requestFocus();` as your final step

This means it should come after you configure the `SnackBar`, after you set the action, and after you make a call to `show()` (regardless of the order you do those things)

If it works on Android TV, where gaining focus is like winning the lottery, it should work for you.